# Cloning a permanent, that is not a creature by itself

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Lets say, I have a noncreature artifact ([Manalith](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Manalith) for example) and something, which temporarily turns it into creature, like [Karn, the Great Creator](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Karn%2C%20the%20Great%20Creator)'s +1 ability. So I have a 3/3 Manalith and I cast [Clone](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Clone) copying the Manalith.

From the rulings for Clone:

> Clone copies exactly what was printed on the original creature and
> nothing more (unless that creature is copying something else or is a
> token; see below). It doesn't copy whether that creature is tapped or
> untapped, whether it has any counters on it or Auras attached to it,
> or any non-copy effects that have changed its power, toughness, types,
> color, or so on.

Does this mean, that I get a plain Manalith? Or do I get a Manalith creature, which dies, because Manalith doesn't have any power or toughness? Or something different?

(I am asking this question, because once a long time ago, I heard a judge talking about some kind of an interaction like this making the clone/copy die, but I am not sure what cards it involved (or even if there actually is such an interaction))

Comment: Big +1 for adding the _exact_ cards and interaction you are referring to, thank you! Only small note is that we have a special `[mtg:CARDNAME]` syntax here which saves you getting Gatherer links yourself, I'll edit that in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get a Manalith.

[Comp Rule](https://media.wizards.com/2022/downloads/MagicCompRules%2020220218.pdf) 707, which handles copying objects, actually has an example that is very similar to your scenario:

> 707.2. When copying an object, the copy acquires the copiable values of the original object’s characteristics.... The copiable values are the values derived from the text printed on the object... as modified by other copy effects, by its face-down status, and by “as . . . enters the
> battlefield” and “as . . . is turned face up” abilities that set power and toughness (and may also set additional characteristics). Other effects (including type-changing and text-changing effects), status, and counters are not copied.
>
> ***Example:** Chimeric Staff is an artifact that reads, “{X}: Chimeric Staff becomes an X/X artifact creature until end of turn.” Clone is a creature that reads, “You may have Clone enter the battlefield as a copy of any creature on the battlefield.” After a Staff has become a 5/5 artifact creature, a Clone enters the battlefield as a copy of it. The Clone is an artifact, not a 5/5 artifact creature. (The copy has the Staff’s ability, however, and will become a creature if that ability is activated.)*

Karn's ability is not in any of the classes of abilities that change copiable values, so it is ignored. Clone sees the Manalith exactly as printed and copies that card, even though by doing so it becomes a non-creature permanent.